# horizontally and vertically center text in a div

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, flexbox

I am struggling to achieve the following:

1) I would like to center my text horizontally and vertically inside a div.

2) I would like a left margin with all the divs except the ones at the extremes. (first at the left and last the right) even when the page resizes.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.homepage-banner-grid {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.homepage-banner-hc-description-items {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.homepage-banner-hc-description-items > div {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#homepage-banner-hc-description-item1 {
  background-color: pink;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#homepage-banner-hc-description-item2 {
  background-color: green;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#homepage-banner-hc-description-item3 {
  background-color: orange;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#homepage-banner-hc-description-item4 {
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.homepage-banner-hc-description-items-icon {
  disply: block;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
.homepage-banner-hc-description-items-text {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="homepage-banner">

  <div class="homepage-banner-grid" id="homepage-banner-hc-description">

    <div class="homepage-banner-hc-description-items" id="homepage-banner-hc-description-item1">
      <div class="homepage-banner-hc-description-items-icon">
        <img src="http://bailbondsstatesboro.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/24_7_service.png" width="100px" height="100px">
      </div>

      <div class="homepage-banner-hc-description-items-text">
        <span>Vivamus massa felis, eleifend quis rhoncus id, finibus id velit.</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="homepage-banner-hc-description-items" id="homepage-banner-hc-description-item2">
      <div class="homepage-banner-hc-description-items-icon">
        <img src="http://bailbondsstatesboro.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/24_7_service.png" width="100px" height="100px">
      </div>
      <div class="homepage-banner-hc-description-items-text">
        <span>Vivamus massa felis, eleifend quis rhoncus id, finibus id velit.</span>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="homepage-banner-hc-description-items" id="homepage-banner-hc-description-item3">
      <div class="homepage-banner-hc-description-items-icon">
        <img src="http://bailbondsstatesboro.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/24_7_service.png" width="100px" height="100px">
      </div>
      <div class="homepage-banner-hc-description-items-text">
        <span>Vivamus massa felis, eleifend quis rhoncus id, finibus id velit.</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="homepage-banner-hc-description-items" id="homepage-banner-hc-description-item4">
      <div class="homepage-banner-hc-description-items-icon">
        <img src="http://bailbondsstatesboro.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/24_7_service.png" width="100px" height="100px">
      </div>
      <div class="homepage-banner-hc-description-items-text">
        <span>Vivamus massa felis, eleifend quis rhoncus id, finibus id velit.</span>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>


</div>
```

I will appreciate any help and correction from our community.

JSfiddle here ----> https://jsfiddle.net/qf3t8725/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1)  to center text horizontally and vertically inside a div.try this

```
.homepage-banner-hc-description-items-text {
    display: flex;
    height: 140px;
    text-align: center;
}

.homepage-banner-hc-description-items-text span {
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If You really want to `margin-left` all divs except first and last You could do like this.

```
.homepage-banner-hc-description-items{
height: 150px;
background-color: yellow;
margin-left: 15px;
}

.homepage-banner-hc-description-items:first-child{
  margin-left:0px;
}
.homepage-banner-hc-description-items:last-child{
  margin-left:0px;
}
```